# Почему не запускается webpack dev-server?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

Глобально установлен  webpack@4.39.1
и  webpack-dev-server@2.9.1

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Marlin05 <livadii17@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue-project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

webpack.config

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

при запуске команды npm run dev

```js
$ npm run dev

> vue-project@1.0.0 dev D:\ASITES\vuerjs\vue-project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

"node" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒७▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒譥▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒ᯮ▒▒塞▒▒ ▒ணࠬ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ 䠩▒▒▒.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-project@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-project@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-11T15_47_47_839Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-11T15_47_47_839Z-debug.log` в студию!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sgvME8Nz